# Using Cursors to iterate through columns and rows assigning each to variables

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to iterate through a table using cursors which looks at the Column name and the value that column holds within that row. I'm wanting to then use both column name and value to be assigned to variables which will be passed into a function to be formatted like so: value

Within my loop I have tried to use a SELECT statement to assign the value of that column in that row to a variable but I only ever get 0 back. I've also tried a brute force method of having a separate variable for each value but then this stops the iteration through the column names. I've only been doing MySQL for a couple of weeks and I'm slowly getting there but this has me stumped.

```
BEGIN

DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE i INT DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE num_rows INT DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE col_name VARCHAR(2000) DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE info INT DEFAULT 0;


DECLARE col_names CURSOR FOR
  SELECT column_name
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE table_name = 'tbl_results';

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;  

OPEN col_names;


the_loop: LOOP

    IF done = 1 THEN
        LEAVE the_loop;
    END IF;

    FETCH col_names INTO col_name;

    SET info = (SELECT col_name FROM tbl_results LIMIT 1);

    SELECT xml_tag(col_name,info); 

END LOOP the_loop;

CLOSE col_names;

END$$
```

xml_tag is just a formatting function which does its job. The output with my code is always, for example, `<id>0</id>`. The value never changes unless I assign info to something specific earlier on.

Comment: SELECT col_name FROM tbl_results will always look for a column called col_name in tbl_results (Which does not exists) Mysql does not do variable substitution. What are you trying to do - it looks like you are attempting to output a table in xml format?

Comment: Ah ok, I was assuming since I could use the select statement in a query and it would return the value that it holds, I could simply have col_name change on each loop and get a new value which would be assigned to the info variable.

Comment: Yes I'm trying to get it into xml format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this sorts out your problem,

```
delimiter $$
create procedure test()
BEGIN

DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE i INT DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE num_rows INT DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE col_name VARCHAR(2000) DEFAULT FALSE;

DECLARE col_names CURSOR FOR
  SELECT column_name
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE table_name = 'tbl_results';

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;  

set @info= null, @col_value= null;

OPEN col_names;


the_loop: LOOP

    FETCH col_names INTO col_name;
    IF done = 1 THEN
        LEAVE the_loop;
    END IF;


    SET @info = concat('SELECT ',col_name,' into @col_value FROM tbl_results LIMIT 1');
    prepare sqlstmt from @info;
    execute sqlstmt;
    deallocate prepare sqlstmt;


    SELECT xml_tag(col_name,@col_value); 

END LOOP the_loop;

CLOSE col_names;
set done = 0;

END$$
```